# Azure AI Search Indexer execution errors/warnings

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am using Azure AI Search to index data from blob storage source. On the initial run of the indexer, which is scheduled in 5 minutes, has to go through 1200 blobs(.pdf,.docx,.xls, etc.). It takes 30 minutes for completion. However, this type of warnings are raised for certain blobs.

`Could not generate projection from input '/document/pages/*'. Check the 'source' or 'sourceContext' property of your projection in your skillset. =$(/document/pages/*) ?map { "chunk": $(/document/pages/*), "customId": $(/document/customId), "title": $(/document/metadata_storage_name), "vector": $(/document/pages/*/vector) }`

This is the skillset configuration that is used:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://***.search.windows.net/$metadata#skillsets/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"***\"",
  "name": "***-skillset",
  "description": "Skillset to chunk documents and generate embeddings",
  "skills": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.AzureOpenAIEmbeddingSkill",
      "name": "#1",
      "description": null,
      "context": "/document/pages/*",
      "resourceUri": "https://***.openai.azure.com",
      "apiKey": "***",
      "deploymentId": "text-embedding-ada-002",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "source": "/document/pages/*"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "embedding",
          "targetName": "vector"
        }
      ],
      "authIdentity": null
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.SplitSkill",
      "name": "#2",
      "description": "Split skill to chunk documents",
      "context": "/document",
      "defaultLanguageCode": "en",
      "textSplitMode": "pages",
      "maximumPageLength": 2000,
      "pageOverlapLength": 200,
      "maximumPagesToTake": 0,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "source": "/document/content"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "textItems",
          "targetName": "pages"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "cognitiveServices": null,
  "knowledgeStore": null,
  "indexProjections": {
    "selectors": [
      {
        "targetIndexName": "***-index",
        "parentKeyFieldName": "parent_id",
        "sourceContext": "/document/pages/*",
        "mappings": [
          {
            "name": "chunk",
            "source": "/document/pages/*",
            "sourceContext": null,
            "inputs": []
          },
          {
            "name": "vector",
            "source": "/document/pages/*/vector",
            "sourceContext": null,
            "inputs": []
          },
          {
            "name": "title",
            "source": "/document/metadata_storage_name",
            "sourceContext": null,
            "inputs": []
          },
          {
            "name": "customId",
            "source": "/document/customId",
            "sourceContext": null,
            "inputs": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "parameters": {
      "projectionMode": "skipIndexingParentDocuments"
    }
  },
  "encryptionKey": null
}
```

The blobs that get the warning are inserted in the index, but some of their chunks don't have value in the vector field. This results in another type of error for the TextSplitSkill for invalid input("text"). I cannot find the reason in the blobs, because they are similar to others that do not raise any warnings. Also, when I ran them for the second time some of the problematic are vectorized and others have different chunks unvectorizied compared to first run.

I went through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-common-errors-warnings, but I cannot find a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your skillset looks correct. You mention that some of your documents are PDFs. Can you check to see if the document id associated with the warnings is for your PDF files? What could be happening is that some or all of your PDFs don't actually have any text content embedded in them, but rather are stored as images, in which case you'll need to add an `imageAction` to your indexer configuration and then an `OCRSkill` to extract text from those images in order to be able to vectorize it.

Comment: To be more specific the documents that caused the errors are 5 pdfs and 2 xlsx. The majority of the blobs in the data source are pdfs and only those few raised the warning. I've checked their content and some of them are pure text with some borders.

Comment: It might look like text to you but we might not be able to actually extract embedded text from them. PDFs are very unique in that you never really know how the data in them is stored. If possible, I would try to put those 5 PDFs in their own blob container and then test if the imageAction + OCRSkill strategy works on them. Because we allow you to process up to 20 documents for free per day, you don't even need to attach a cognitive services key to test this.